# Using HiveQL, how do I pull the row with the highest integer?

Tags: hiveql

I have a table with a few million rows of data that looks like this:

```
+---------------+--------------+-------------------+
| page          | search_term  |    interactions   |
+---------------+--------------+-------------------+
| /mom          |  pizza       |        15         |
| /dad          |  pizza       |         8         |
| /uncle        |  pizza       |         2         |
| /brother      |  pizza       |         7         |
| /mom          |  pasta       |        12         |
| /dad          |  pasta       |        23         |
+---------------+--------------+-------------------+
```

My goal is to run a HiveQL Query that will return the largest 'interactions' number for each *unique* page/term combo. For example:

```
+---------------+--------------+-------------------+
| page          |  search_term |    interactions   |
+---------------+--------------+-------------------+
| /dad          |  pasta       |        23         |
| /mom          |  pizza       |        15         |
+---------------+--------------+-------------------+
```

How would I write this considering that each unique page has hundreds of thousands of search_terms, but I only want to pull the one search_term with the most interactions?

I have tried using max(interactions) and max(struct(interactions, search_term)).col1 but have had no luck. My output is consistently giving me all of the search_terms for each page no matter how many interactions.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use row_number() analytic function:

`select  page, search_term, interactions 
from
    (select page, search_term, interactions, 
        row_number() over (partition by page order by interactions desc ) rn
    )s
where rn = 1;`